# Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'path' of module exports inside circular dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path

[node --trace-warnings ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTAEa.png)I encounter a diffult. Does the displayed error relate to the version of node used?

In my apps.js file I have entered the const path.

I work with express, nodejs, and mongo db.

My user can create their own sauce.

But when I write nodemon server I have this message on my terminal VSC.
I have v16.13.1 of nodejs.

```js
//app.js//

const path = require("path");


app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images")));
```

Comment: What is you node version. Such problems have seen in node 14 version. is surge installed in your system ?

Comment: @SahilRajpal I have v16.13.1 of nodejs.

Comment: @SahilRajpal I followed the installation procedure, I did not change anything in the environment variables.

Comment: @SahilRajpal I updated my question and added a screenshot, I used the command 0
node --trace-warnings .to see the problem.From what I understand I need to add environment variables ?

Comment: @SahilRajpal I succeeded, it was a syntax error, I misplaced my const path.